# Fast bounded minimum of a 2nd order function

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I need *fast* a C++ (or C) function which finds the minimum of a function of form *ax²+bx* in the *[lo, hi]* real interval. For testing purposes one can assume that *a* and *b* are uniformly sampled from *[lo, hi]*.

This is my take at the moment. How can I make it faster?

```
template <typename real>
real QuadraticMinimizerGenericV1(real a, real b, real lo, real hi) {
    real x = lo;
    if (a > 0) {
        x = -b / (2 * a);
        x = std::min(hi, std::max(lo, x));
    }
    else if ((a < 0) || (a == 0 && b != 0)) {
        real flo = lo * lo * a + lo * b;
        real fhi = hi * hi * a + hi * b;
        x = (flo <= fhi) ? lo : hi;
    }
    else if (a == 0 && b == 0) {
        x = UniformRandom(lo, hi);
    }
    return x;
}
```

**EDIT**: the call to UniformRandom is important for reasons not detailed here.

Comment: `UniformRandom(lo, hi);` - instead of this, usually `lo` or `hi` is returned.

Comment: faster is relative. What is `real`? For really big numbers `-b / (2 * a)` is slower than `-b / (a + a)` and `lo * lo * a + lo * b` is slower than `lo * (lo * a + b)`.

Comment: Why do you return `UniformRandom(lo, hi)` and not just a constant like `lo`? Generating random numbers is generally very slow (especially compared to the rest of the function). By the way, how the function is called in practice? It should be pretty fast if the `UniformRandom` call is never done. There is not much to do at this level (it is a bit like optimizing an expression like `ax+b`).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: real is either float or double

Comment: @JérômeRichard: UniformRandom is called in approximately 1% of the cases

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do apart from few micro-optimizations (assuming fast-math is not used since it should already do that). Here is some minor improvements:

```
template <typename real>
real QuadraticMinimizerGenericV1(real a, real b, real lo, real hi) {
    real x = lo;
    if (a > 0) {
        x = b / (-2 * a);
        x = std::min(std::max(x, lo), hi);
    }
    else if ((a < 0) | ((a == 0) & (b != 0))) {
        real flo = lo * (lo * a + b);
        real fhi = hi * (hi * a + b);
        x = (flo <= fhi) ? lo : hi;
    }
    else if (a == 0 && b == 0) {
        x = UniformRandom(lo, hi);
    }
    return x;
}
```

The generated assembly code with `-O3` using GCC or Clang is pretty good already. It just does few instruction per branch. A branchless computation might be faster regarding the use-case but harmful without more information/assumptions.

The main possible optimization is to use **SIMD instructions** in the caller code if possible. It should be done manually since compiler cannot automatically vectorize the random number generation (and will have a hard time optimizing out conditional branches). This optimization should be combined with a branchless optimization.